# How can I associate xml text with a preceding empty element in Python?

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I have inherited some xml that I need to process in Python. I am using `xml.etree.cElementTree`, and I am having some trouble associating text that occurs after an empty element with that empty element's tag. The xml is quite a bit more complicated than I what I have pasted below, but I have simplified it to make the problem clearer (I hope!).

The result I would like to have is a dict like this:

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
{(9, 1): 'As they say, A student has usually three maladies:', (9, 2): 'poverty, itch, and pride.'}
```

The tuples can also contain strings (e.g., `('9', '1')`). I really don't care at this early stage.

Here is the XML:

**test1.xml**

```
<div1 type="chapter" num="9">
  <p>
    <section num="1"/> <!-- The empty element -->
      As they say, A student has usually three maladies: <!-- Here lies the trouble -->
    <section num="2"/> <!-- Another empty element -->
      poverty, itch, and pride.
  </p>
</div1>
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

**Attempt 1**

```
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.parse('test1.xml')
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> chapter = root.attrib['num']
>>> d = dict()
>>> for p in root:
    for section in p:
        d[(int(chapter), int(section.attrib['num']))] = section.text


>>> d
{(9, 2): None, (9, 1): None}    # This of course makes sense, since the elements are empty
```

**Attempt 2**

```
>>> for p in root:
    for section, text in zip(p, p.itertext()):    # unfortunately, p and p.itertext() are two different lengths, which also makes sense
        d[(int(chapter), int(section.attrib['num']))] = text.strip()


>>> d
{(9, 2): 'As they say, A student has usually three maladies:', (9, 1): ''}
```

As you can see in the latter attempt, `p` and `p.itertext()` are two different lengths. The value of `(9, 2)` is the value I am trying to associate with key `(9, 1)`, and the value I want to associate with `(9, 2)` does not even show up in `d` (since `zip` truncates the longer `p.itertext()`).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `.tail`?

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

txt = """<div1 type="chapter" num="9">
         <p>
           <section num="1"/> <!-- The empty element -->
             As they say, A student has usually three maladies: <!-- Here lies the trouble -->
           <section num="2"/> <!-- Another empty element -->
             poverty, itch, and pride.
         </p>
         </div1>"""
root = ET.fromstring(txt)
for p in root:
    for s in p:
        print s.attrib['num'], s.tail
```

Comment: Brilliant. Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<div1 type="chapter" num="9">
  <p>
    <section num="1"/>
      As they say, A student has usually three maladies:
    <section num="2"/>
      poverty, itch, and pride.
  </p>
</div1>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

result = {}
for chapter in soup.find_all(type='chapter'):
    for section in chapter.find_all('section'):
      result[(chapter['num'], section['num'])] = section.next_sibling.strip()

import pprint
pprint.pprint(result)
```

This prints:

```
{(u'9', u'1'): u'As they say, A student has usually three maladies:',
 (u'9', u'2'): u'poverty, itch, and pride.'}
```